# 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port when deploying Harbor behind NLB

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, argo, harbor

We are planning to deploy NLB to access Harbor deployed on EKS.. We have deployed AWS load balancer controller on the cluster.
Below is my values file

```
harbor:
  expose:
    type: loadBalancer
    tls:
      enabled: true
      auto:
        commonName: "xxx"
    loadBalancer:
      name: harbor-dev
      annotations:
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type": "nlb-ip"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type": "instance"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets": "xxx"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port": "traffic-port"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-success-codes": "200-399"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes": "preserve_client_ip.enabled=true"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal": "true"
        "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert": "xxx"
        "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname": "https://harbor-dev.xxx"
        "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl": "300"
  externalURL: https://harbor-dev.xxx
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    resourcePolicy: keep
  nginx:
    tls:
      enabled: true
```

Deployment seems successful but when i am trying to access Harbor, i am getting the below error :

400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

**Methods tried to resolve the error :**

I tried updating the helm chart such that the load balancer service targetport point to 8080 (or) http but no luck

Also i tried updating the HTTPS target group manually point to 8080 but i am getting the error like "Too many redirects"

So i want to know if anyone has used this particular approach to deploy Harbor behind NLB and faced such issues

**Working solution :**

I have tried deploying Harbor behind ALB using ingress which is working fine, but i want to provide the access for other AWS accounts running for which i want to deploy NLB so that i can have VPC endpoint service to expose.